# How to change string revision format in C#?

Tags: c#

As for my requirement i want to change string revision format newly. Based on below format.

```
E.g:
 ______________
|Test-A       |
|  ...        +
|Test-Z       | ==>IF Test-Z then Next time i need to create Revision "AA" 
|  ...        +
|Test-AA      |
| ...         +
|Test-AZ      |==>IF Test-AZ then Next time i need to create Revision "BA" 
| ...         +
|Test-BA      |
| ...         +
|Test-BZ      |==>IF Test-BZ then Next time i need to create Revision "CA" 
| ...         +
|Test-CA      |
| ...         +
|Test-CZ      |==>IF Test-CZ then Next time i need to create Revision "DA" 
+_____________+
```

**`E.g2 :`**

A, B ....Z & AA, BB....AZ then I need to change BA...BB, BC....BZ & CA, CB....CZ.

Please help me to solve this task.

Comment: what you want? where is tried code?

Comment: First time Revision is 'A' it will be stored in SQL DB. Eg. Department name is 'Test' already inserted in DB & the revision is 'A'. second time same Department name is coming like 'Test'. So, this time i have to create new revision like 'B' some thing like.

Comment: If same Department name coming as 26 times that time i have to change Revision as 'Z'.

Answer (score 1):

I would think that you need two methods to do so:
1.: A String to Integer method which returns you a number where you can add 1. 
2.: A method which converts back the number into a string.

I'm currently on my tablet, so here just some untested code:

```
private int StringToInt(string version)
{
    int returnValue =0;
    // Iterate through the given string char by char and convert it to an integer
    // (A=65 in the ascii table, therefore we nned to substract it)
    for(int i=0; i<version.Length;i++)
    {
        // The alphabet has 26 chars so we just think of your version
        // as a base26 number and convert it to a base10 number.
        retunValue+=Math.Pow(26,i)*((int)version[version.Length-1-i]-65);
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

and

```
private string IntToSting(int value)
{
    String returnValue=String.Empty;
    while(value /26>0)
    {
        // % is the modulo operator. eg if value was 27, value%26 == 1
        returnValue=((char)(value%26+65)).ToString()+returnValue;
        value-=value%26;
    }

    returnValue=((char)(value%26+65)).ToString() +returnValue;
}
```

Note that these methods only work for capital letters and that they do not handle special cases as for example IntToString(0);

You can now simply use it by calling the methods and adding 1 to the result of StringToInteger before calling IntToString.

```
version = IntToString(StringToInteger(version)+1);
```

Comment: error while calling IntToString Method ----> Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'string.String(char*)' has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like homework:

```
public class RevisionNumber
{
    private static readonly string[] _Representations = new[] { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z" };
    private int _Value;

    public void Increment()
    {
        _Value++;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        var result = String.Empty;
        var value = _Value;

        while (value >= _Representations.Length)
        {
            result = _Representations[(int)value % _Representations.Length] + result;
            value /= _Representations.Length;
            value--;
        }

        return _Representations[(int)value] + result;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var revision = new RevisionNumber();

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(revision);
                revision.Increment();
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

The corresponding [fiddle is here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KO8dPu).

Comment: After `AZ` you go to `AAA` - I think OP wanted `BA`, `BB`, `BC` etc

Comment: I think I managed to get it even easier -http://rextester.com/MJIMV22975

Comment: @Jamiec: Then after `ZZ` it starts over with `AA` instead with `AAA`

Comment: yes it does - im not sure even the OP thought beyond `ZZ` :)